# Find by Selector Style Scraping

Tags: css, ruby, mechanize

I'm doing a "Scraper" for my university and I need to select all the "tbody" that contain the "background color: #bebeff". I tried several of the w3schools Selectors and I can not do it. Is there any way to do that ?.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ERqh.png)

By the way, I use Mechanize Gem with Ruby.

Try this:

```
 require 'mechanize'
 require 'csv'

 agent = Mechanize.new
 page = agent.get('http://www.rockauto.com/es/catalog/')
 page = page.link_with(:text => 'Español').click
 page = page.link_with(:text => 'FORD').click
 page = page.link_with(:text => '2012').click
 page = page.link_with(:text => 'F-150').click
 page = page.link_with(:text => "3.7L V6").click
 page = page.link_with(:text => "Freno y Maza de Rueda").click
 page = page.link_with(:text => "Pastilla de Freno").click
 page = page.search('[style~=bebeff]')


 puts page.inspect
```

I hope there is some solution.

Greetings and thank you friends.

Comment: You want `*=`, not `~=`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the style in each tbody is setted as "background: #bebeff; ", you could try by using `=`. `^=` would also work.

```
require 'mechanize'
require 'csv'

agent = Mechanize.new
page = agent.get 'http://www.rockauto.com/es/catalog/'
page = page.link_with(text: 'Español').click
page = page.link_with(text: 'FORD').click
page = page.link_with(text: '2012').click
page = page.link_with(text: 'F-150').click
page = page.link_with(text: '3.7L V6').click
page = page.link_with(text: 'Freno y Maza de Rueda').click
page = page.link_with(text: 'Pastilla de Freno').click
page = page.search 'tbody[style="background: #bebeff; "]'
p page.inspect
```

Comment: I have a doubt, after "#bebeff;(space)"] it takes a space, because it takes it, but if I put it, it does not return anything, I just ask to understand, the problem is already solved.

Greetings.

Comment: Yes, it's because they've used an extra space, and using `=` you compare for the exact style, otherwise by using ~ you should specify one string of those separated by one whitespace, like `'tbody[style~="#bebeff;"]'` (quotes needed), and `'tbody[style^="background: #bebeff"]'` would also work.

Comment: Buena, gracias sebastian, despues me di cuenta que eres de Chile Tb... Mil gracias compadre.